# What control to use in windows forms for a search result with pagination, like a Repeater from Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was asked to look if in windows forms c# i can make somehow to be the same layout as a repeater from Asp.
I attach a printscreen.
I am new to windows forms application.
I tried with DataRepeater as stated here but can not have a pagination as you will see i image attached. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx
[image]

Comment: You'll have to create your own paging or use a 3rd-part component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a simple tutorial about implementing paging with a DataGrid.  This should get you the basics and you can further modify it to meet your needs.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16303/DataGrid-Paging-C-Windows-Forms

Comment: Ok, I will take a look. I am sure that project leader would ask to have exactly the same, I mean Prec, 1 2 3 4 5. I will think for a solution. Thanks. After holidays I will test it ;)

Comment: but is it possible to have pages enumeration like in web?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "page enumeration".

Comment: I meant to have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. In the meaning time project leader told me that won't be necessary to be exactly so. Thanks.